# Tileset for HTML5 canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, image, tile

I'm trying to make a game in HTML5 canvas, but instead of uploading a ton of images I want to just upload one image that has all of the tiles on it. The problem is, I don't know how to make only one part of the image show up. Basically I want to do what Google does with this image: http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo27.png except with fixed height/width tiles. Can someone explain to me how to do this? Also, if it's different in canvas than in a regular html page without canvas, how would I do it in canvas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the slicing parameters of `drawImage`

```
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
```

[image]

- `sx`, `sy`: left and top offset of the part to be sliced
- `sWidth`, `sHeight`: dimensions of the part to be sliced
- `dx`, `dy`: left and top offset for the image on the canvas to be rendered at
- `dWidth`, `dHeight`: image dimensions on the canvas

More info at: **[Using images - Slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Slicing) (MDC)**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SpriteJS https://github.com/batiste/sprite.js/blob/master/sprite.js there the work is based on offset at the moment of drawing the sprite from a single picture.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with GWT:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwt_hmtl5